# PCF Cloud - want to update Tomcat Max Header Size Parameter

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, pcf

We have ran into

> "Request Header is too large"

error in our PCF Cloud environment where we are using Tomcat from PCF Container. We have gone through various threads on this error and understand that we need to increase the max allowed header size configuration for the tomcat. However, we do not have a clear instructions on how we can update this setting if our Tomcat is in PCF Environment ? Its a Spring boot application but we are deploying WAR file by using external tomcat from PCF container. We tried setting the header size (`server.max-http-header-size=65536`) in the `application.properties` file but this fix is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the max HTTP header size, edit your app configuration file:

application.properties format

server.max-http-header-size=20000

application.yml format

server:

max-http-header-size: 20000